# Proof that $\mu$ is a mass distribution

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $F\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ a compact subset. We define $\text{spt}(\mu)=\bigcap_{F\in \mathcal{F}}F$, on what $\mathcal{F}=\{F\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n: \mu(\mathbb{R}^n\setminus F)=0\}$. We say that mu is a measure in $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ if $spt(\mu)\subseteq A$.
We say that a $\mu$ measure is a mass distribution if $0<\mu(\mathbb{R}^n<\infty$ and if $\mu$ is a measure on a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Furthermore, given a finite word $(i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_k)$, we define its cylinder
$C(i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_k)=\left\{(i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_k,q_{k+1},\ldots): q_{j}\in \mathcal{A} , \forall\hspace{0.1cm} j\geq k+1\right\}$, on what $\mathcal{A}=\{1,\ldots,m\}$.

We define $\mu(C(i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_k))=(r_{i_1}\cdots r_{i_k})^s$ (where $r_{i_j}$ are the similarity factors $S_{i_j}:\mathbb{R}^\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$).

Knowing that $\left(\sum_{j=1}^m r_j^s\right)=1$. We have to

\begin{equation}
\mu(C(i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_k))=(r_{i_1}\cdots r_{i_k})^s(\sum_{j=1}^m r_j^s)=\sum_{j=1}^m (r_{i_1}\cdots r_{i_k}c_j)^s=\sum_{j=1}^m\mu(C(i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_k,r_j)).
\end{equation}

My question is: Why is $\mu$ a mass distribution in $\mathcal{A}^{\mathbb{N}}= \{(i_1,i_2,i_3,\ldots): 1\leq i_n\leq m, \forall \hspace{0.1cm} n\in \mathbb{N}\}$?

Thanks for the help!!!

OBS: the $r_{i_j}$ is the similarity factor $S_{i_j}$, that is, $d(S_{i_j}(x),S_{i_j}(y))=r_{i_j}d(x, y)$ for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Furthermore, $s$ is the only real number such that $\left(\sum_{j=1}^mr_j^s\right)=1$.

One of my doubts is to know how to extend $\mu$ in $\mathcal{A}^\mathbb{N}$ knowing that this is worth it $\mu(C(i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_k))=(r_{i_1}\cdots r_{i_k})^s(\sum_{j=1}^m r_j^s)=\sum_{j=1}^m (r_{i_1}\cdots r_{i_k}c_j)^s=\sum_{j=1}^m\mu(C(i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_k,r_j))$. Remembering that $\mathcal{A}^{\mathbb{N}}= \{(i_1,i_2,i_3,\ldots): 1\leq i_n\leq m, \forall \hspace{0.1cm} n\in \mathbb{N}\}$. Is it a little clearer now? can you help me to show that $\mu$ is a mass distribution in $\mathcal{A}^{\mathbb{N}}$

Comment: what are $c_j, s, \mathcal A,S$? What is the domain of the words?

Comment: Hi, I edited the post, can you understand now? the $r_{i_j}$ is the similarity factor $S_{i_j}$, that is, $d(S_{i_j}(x),S_{i_j}(y))=r_{i_j}d(x, y)$ for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Furthermore, $s$ is the only real number such that $\left(\sum_{j=1}^mr_j^s\right)=1$

Comment: It's still totally not clear. $\mu$ is not even defined on $\mathcal A^{\mathbb N}$. And what are the "words"?

Comment: one of my doubts is to know how to extend $\mu$ in $\mathcal{A}^\mathbb{N}$ knowing that this is worth it $\mu(C(i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_k))=(r_{i_1}\cdots r_{i_k})^s(\sum_{j=1}^m r_j^s)=\sum_{j=1}^m (r_{i_1}\cdots r_{i_k}c_j)^s=\sum_{j=1}^m\mu(C(i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_k,r_j))$. Remembering that $\mathcal{A}^{\mathbb{N}}= \{(i_1,i_2,i_3,\ldots): 1\leq i_n\leq m, \forall \hspace{0.1cm} n\in \mathbb{N}\}$. Is it a little clearer now? can you help me to show that $\mu$ is a mass distribution in $\mathcal{A}^{\mathbb{N}}$

Comment: Words are finite strings...for example $(i_1,i_2,i_3,\ldots,i_k)$.

Comment: by your definition $\mu$ is a mass distribution if its support is in a bounded subset of $\mathbb R^n$. How do you propose to find any such set inside $\mathcal A^{\mathbb N}$?

Comment: So the definition of mass distribution in the context of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is this:  We say that a $\mu$ measure is a mass distribution if $0<\mu(\mathbb{R}^n)<\infty$ and if $\mu$ is a measure on a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: exactly. But how is $\mathcal A$ related to $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: So $\mathcal{A}=\{1,2,\cdots,m\}$, $\mathcal{A}^{\mathbb{N}}=\{(i_1,i_2,i_3,\ldots): 1\leq i_n\leq m, \forall  n\in \mathbb{N}\}$. We could identify the set of finite sequences (words) with $\mathbb{R}^n$, but I don't know how we can do that for the set of infinite words, that is, for $\mathcal{A}^{\mathbb{N}}$.

Comment: In this pdf he teaches how to make this extension, but I didn't quite understand how it works. On page 24: https://www.math.ru.nl/~mueger/THESES/Jesper_van_den_Eijnden_Bachelor_2018.pdf

Comment: This measure $\mu$ is NOT defined on $\mathbb R^n$ on that PDF, so it has no sense asking whether is is a mass measure or not...

Comment: I wanted to understand how to extend the definition of mass distribution in the context of sequential infinites instead of $\mathbb{R}^n$. And prove why $\mu$ is a mass distribution in $\mathcal{A}^{\mathbb{N}}$. Is it clear now?

Comment: Changing the requirement from $0 < \mu(\mathbb{R}^n) < \infty$ to $0 < \mu(\mathcal{A}^{\mathbb{N}}) < \infty$ is no issue. But for "bounded" to make sense, you need a metric space. What distance function on $\mathcal{A}^{\mathbb{N}}$ do you want to use - maybe $L^1$ Manhattan distance?

Comment: @aschepler Maybe, but would you know how to show that $\mu$ is a mass distribution in $\mathcal{A}^{\mathbb{N}}$?

Comment: I don't think that $\mu$ is entirely well-defined. What is $\mu(\mathcal{A}^m \times \{1\}^{\mathbb{N}})$?